# How do i upgrade my ruby version on windows, i have installed that using railsinstaller along with rails and gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Below is the error which i get when i installed rails installer and created app named simple blog and the, when i did

```
rails server
```

I received the error mentioned below

```
Could not find gem 'web-console (>= 3.3.0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

Then when i did

```
gem install web-console
```

It returns the following error

```
C:\Sites\simpleblog>gem install web-console
ERROR:  Error installing web-console:
        zeitwerk requires Ruby version >= 2.4.4.
```

Comment: I highly recommend looking into WSL2 on windows. As a rails dev that hated dual booting into Ubuntu and not having the stomach to buy another $3k macbook pro it changed my life.

Comment: what is your Ruby version?

Comment: Ruby version is 2.3.3 @Nikhil

Comment: So if your version is 2.3.3 and gem dependency requires > 2.4.4 then update your ruby version to 2.5 or choose web-console previous gem version which can support 2.3.3

Comment: I'd recommend using [Ruby Installer](https://rubyinstaller.org/) on Windows to get some level of "`rbenv`" etc experience on non-Windows - essentially to keep your _existing_ versions/env working and hopefully avoid possible gem dependency chain issues that could  affect your existing apps.